# Within a single application can I get CAS to reauthenticate for a specific page?

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I've a (WordPress) website that's secured using CAS.  Single sign on is fine for most pages, but a few pages contain sensitive information and require a little more security.  For those pages I would like to ask the user to re-enter their password.  Is that possible with CAS?

(I did wonder whether I could somehow have those pages behave as separate applications that use the "renew" parameter, but that doesn't seem straightforward.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends how WP is integrated with CAS. If it's able to submit renew=true for certain parameters, then yes you could. This is probably a limitation of the WP plugin.

Comment: Thanks Misagh.  I'm using the [wpCAS plug-in](http://maisonbisson.com/projects/wpcas/): there didn't seem to be many to choose from!  I don't see any mention of the `renew=true` parameter on that site, so perhaps it isn't supported.  Is there an alternative plug-in you can recommend that does support `renew=true`?

Comment: I don't know of any alternate plugins sadly. Perhaps another option would be add those sensitive pages into CAS by patterns as service definitions, and then disable SSO participation for those services. This will effectively be renew=true.

Comment: Clever idea Misagh - thanks.  I'll look into that approach.

Comment: Sure. For extra security you may also want to consider mfa.

Comment: Thanks, although I think Multi-Factor Authentication (I assume that's what you are referring to) is a little beyond what I need.  However, regarding disabling of SSO participation, would that be the `ssoEnabled` property that seems to turn up when I google the topic?  I haven't been able to find out where to use that yet: I would expect it to be within, for example, a `RegexRegisteredService` bean's definition in `deployerConfigContext.xml`, is that right?  (I've tried `<property name="ssoEnabled" value="false" />` in there but it doesn't have the desired effect.)

Comment: Yes that should do it. Let me explain: (though I am not sure what version you are on) that setting only takes effect when an authn request is submitted to CAS at which time CAS will ignore the existence of an SSO session and will proceed to challenge you for credentials. If that request is never submitted by the client, it will not have any impact. Your client likely is keeping track of the authn session after the initial signin. It seems like you do have to find a better WP CAS plugin, or mod the existing one.